# c# Relative position of elements in Windows Form

Tags: c#, winforms, splitter

I try to create simple app with 2 columns using SpliterContainer and control panel with buttons. And I would like that on every screen it will look good. That's why I decided to use relative position of elements.

I read documentation and different forums, but I get something strange. Second column of splitter doesn't appear at all.

[image: Result]

Please, can you help me find the reason of that problem?

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;

            int screenWidth = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width;
            int screenHeight = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height;

            //set form size
            this.Size = new Size(screenWidth, screenHeight);

            //set button panel size
            const double percentOfHeightPanel = 0.05;
            int heightOfPanelButton = Convert.ToInt32(screenHeight * percentOfHeightPanel);
            this.panel_button.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(screenWidth, heightOfPanelButton);
            this.panel_button.Location = new Point(0, 0);


            //set splitContainer size
            int widthOfContainer = Convert.ToInt32(0.5 * screenWidth);
            int heightOfContainers = Convert.ToInt32(screenHeight * (0.95));
            splitContainer1.Panel1.MinimumSize = new Size(widthOfContainer, heightOfContainers);
            splitContainer1.Panel2.MinimumSize = new Size(widthOfContainer, heightOfContainers);
            splitContainer1.Location = new Point(0, heightOfPanelButton);
            //this.splitContainer1.Panel2MinSize = screenWidth - widthOfContainer;

            //set textBox size                
            this.textBox1.Multiline = true;
            this.textBox1.Location = new Point(0, heightOfPanelButton);
            this.textBox1.MinimumSize = new System.Drawing.Size(widthOfContainer, heightOfContainers);

            this.textBox2.Multiline = true;
            this.textBox2.Location = new Point(widthOfContainer, heightOfPanelButton);
            this.textBox1.MinimumSize = new System.Drawing.Size(widthOfContainer, heightOfContainers);
        }
```

Comment: reading code to identify the problem related to something **visual** isn't easy. You should post some screen shot to show what is wrong with your **visual** stuff.

Comment: @KingKing I add image

Comment: Why do you think the second column of your splitContainer doesn't appear? You should set its `BorderStyle` to `BorderStyle.FixedSingle` to see it clearer.

Comment: @KingKing I add BorderStyle and you are right. But why location of text box not the same as panel of splitContainer?

Comment: You should update the screen shot too (with `FixedSingle` border)

Comment: Your textbox is a child control of your `splitContainer1.Panel1`, so it's `Location` should be `Point.Empty` if you want it to be the same location with your `splitContainer1`. (The `Location` is calculated in the **Parent coordinates system**).

Answer (score 1):

If you want two have two splitter panels of the same size set

```
splitContainer1.SplitterDistance = 
                          (splitContainer1.Width - splitContainer1.SplitterWidth) / 2;
```

Then set

```
splitContainer1.IsSplitterFixed = true;
```

You can set these two properties manually at design time. The user will then not be able to resize the panels and the panels will automatically resize to be of same size.

Consider using a `TableLayoutPanel` instead.

If further, the two sides should look the same, place your controls on a `UserControl` and place two instances of them into the two panels with a docked property set to `Fill`.

Comment: Thanx. Is it possible remove splitContainer1.SplitterWidth or some tricks, because minimum width >=1

Comment: @Ray: Maybe you could use a `TableLayoutPanel` with just two columns and set their widths to 50% each. This would have the same effect.